# How i can reformat this code to follow DRY principle

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, dry

my views.py

```
    from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter, OrderingFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

from .serializers import *
from .permissions import IsAdminOrReadOnly
from .filters import *


class ProductsAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('title', 'category__name')
    filter_fields = ('category',)
    ordering_fields = ('price',)
    filterset_class = ProductsFilter


class ProductsAPIUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly, )


class ProductsAPIRemove(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly, )


class StorageAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsStorage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsStorageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)


class StorageAPIUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsStorage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsStorageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)


class StorageAPIRemove(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsStorage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsStorageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)


class ProductSignAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductSign.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSignSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)


class ProductSignAPIUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductSign
    serializer_class = ProductSignSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)


class ProductSignAPIRemove(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsStorage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSignSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
```

my urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView

from InternetShop import settings
from InternetShopApp.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/products/', ProductsAPIList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/products/<int:pk>/', ProductsAPIUpdate.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/productsremove/<int:pk>/', ProductsAPIRemove.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/storage/', StorageAPIList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/storage/<int:pk>/', StorageAPIList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/storageremove/<int:pk>/', StorageAPIList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/productsign/', ProductSignAPIList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/productsign/<int:pk>/', ProductSignAPIUpdate.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/productsignremove/<int:pk>/', ProductSignAPIRemove.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/login/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/v1/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/v1/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/v1/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In my views i repeat a lot of identic stuff for different models(products, storage, productsign) therefore i disturb DRY principle , and i need to cut back some code. Maybe i can somehow habitate from previous classes or use something else.
In my views i repeat a lot of identic stuff for different models(products, storage, productsign) therefore i disturb DRY principle , and i need to cut back some code. Maybe i can somehow habitate from previous classes or use something else.

Comment: If your code is working, your question would probably be a much better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `ModelViewSet` to combine the above three classes into one. The `ModelViewSet` class has `create`, `retrieve`, `update`, `partial_update`, `destroy` and `list` methods for all of the `GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` APIs.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ProductsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('title', 'category__name')
    filter_fields = ('category',)
    ordering_fields = ('price',)
    filterset_class = ProductsFilter
```

And in urls.py, you could just set one endpoint for all CRUD requests.

```
...

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/products', ProductsViewSet, basename="product"),
    # path('api/v1/products/', ProductsAPIList.as_view()),
    # path('api/v1/products/<int:pk>/', ProductsAPIUpdate.as_view()),
    # path('api/v1/productsremove/<int:pk>/', ProductsAPIRemove.as_view()),
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then, for `list()` and `create()` methods (GET, POST), you can use `api/v1/products`, and `retrieve()`, `update()`, `partial_update()`, and `delete()` methods (GET, PUT, PATCH, UPDATE), you can use `api/v1/products/<int:pk>`.